# В чём заключается ошибка? Python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, design

Прописываю данный код и выдаёт ошибку

```py
class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        loadUi("main.ui", self)
        
        self.settings_hm.clicked.connect(self.setting)

        self.porydk = 1



class Settings_l(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Settings_l, self).__init__()
        loadUi("settings.ui", self)
        

        ...

    def new(self):

        self.porydk += 1

        

        self.groupBox_2 = QGroupBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.groupBox_2.setMinimumSize(QSize(411, 251))
        self.groupBox_2.setMaximumSize(QSize(411, 251))
        self.groupBox_2.setCheckable(False)
        self.groupBox_2.setStyleSheet(u"border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;\n"
"border-radius: 10;")
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName(f"groupBox_{self.x}")
```

Ошибка - AttributeError: 'Settings_l' object has no attribute 'porydk'

Как это исправить?

Comment: Объявляете вы в объекте одного класса: `self.porydk = 1`, а вызываете `self.porydk += 1` в другом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю для чего вам это нужно, но если это свойство нужно в `MainWindow`, можно его сделать свойством **класса**

Пример:

```
class MainWindow(QDialog):
    porydk = 1  # Свойство класса

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        loadUi("main.ui", self)

        self.settings_hm.clicked.connect(self.setting)

class Settings_l(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Settings_l, self).__init__()
        loadUi("settings.ui", self)

        ...

    def new(self):
        # Обращаемся и меняем свойство класса
        MainWindow.porydk += 1

        self.groupBox_2 = QGroupBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.groupBox_2.setMinimumSize(QSize(411, 251))
        self.groupBox_2.setMaximumSize(QSize(411, 251))
        self.groupBox_2.setCheckable(False)
        self.groupBox_2.setStyleSheet(u"border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;\n"
                                      "border-radius: 10;")
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName(f"groupBox_{self.x}")
```

Но мне кажется, что это свойство **должно было быть в конструкторе `Settings_l`**:

```
class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        loadUi("main.ui", self)
        
        self.settings_hm.clicked.connect(self.setting)


class Settings_l(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Settings_l, self).__init__()
        loadUi("settings.ui", self)
        
        self.porydk = 1
        ...

    def new(self):
        self.porydk += 1

        self.groupBox_2 = QGroupBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.groupBox_2.setMinimumSize(QSize(411, 251))
        self.groupBox_2.setMaximumSize(QSize(411, 251))
        self.groupBox_2.setCheckable(False)
        self.groupBox_2.setStyleSheet(u"border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;\n"
"border-radius: 10;")
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName(f"groupBox_{self.x}")
```